# When a JS Variable DOES not play nice and will not get populated

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple variable that's accepting a JSON Object...

Here's all the code:

This should help since I decided that it's clean enough not to expose where I'm working.

```
var server = "00.00.000.00:8800";
var webServices = "http://" + server + "/somedir/ws/";

var networksURL;
var sitesURL;
var resourcesURL;
var componentsURL;

networksURL = webServices + 'config/networks';
sitesURL =  webServices + 'config/sites';
resourcesURL =  webServices + 'config/resources';
componentsURL =  webServices + 'config/components';


var treeData;
var netsSites;
var sitesRes;
var resComp;

var myType;
var myUrl;
var jsonLen;
var myData1;
var JSONModified;
var dataToget;


function getInfo(myUrl, callback) {

    console.log("INSIDE GETINFO:: " + myUrl);

    var myData;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: myUrl,
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        //data: "{}",                       //NOT USED unless you have parameters
        //jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',   //NOT USED unless the server is set up properly
        dataType: 'json',
        //Switch to jsonp ONLY if your JSON CALLBACK is set up properly on the server
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
            jsonLen = data.length;
            myData1 = data;
            //If successful, show the data, if not, show error
            if (!data) {

                console.log("Error");
                //$("#alert_json").text("There was an error processing the your request.");
                return false;
            } else {

                myData = JSON.stringify(data);
                //**************************** STEP 1 ***************************
                //Now send to processing (STEP 1) add the prefixes for the JSTree
                JSONModified = addPrefix(myData);
                //console.log(JSONModified);
                //End sending back the data
                //**************************** END STEP 1 ***********************

                //console.log("Data found: " + myData);
                //$("#alert_json").text(JSONModified);
                if (JSONModified)
                {
                    callback(JSONModified);
                } else {
                    callback('[{"data":"No site data found..."}]');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //console.log("Data not found or is not available at this time");
            //$("#alert_json").text("Data not found or is not available at this time");
            callback(null);
        }
    });
}

//PRELIMINARY - CALL THE FUNCTION passing in the JSON object you wish to retreive
function buildTree(typJSON) {

    myType = typJSON;


    //DETERMINE The type of JSON and then set it below.
    switch (typJSON) {

        case "nets":
            dataToget = networksURL;
            break;
        case "sties":
            dataToget = sitesURL;
            break;
        case "res":
            dataToget = resourcesURL;
            break;
        case "comp":
            dataToget = componentsURL;
            break;
        default:
            dataToget = 'Unknown Error';
            break;
    }



    getInfo(dataToget, function(data) {

        if (!data) {

            console.log("Return Value: NULL");
            return false;
        } else {

            //console.log("Return Value: SUCCESS!");
            //console.log(JSONModified);
            // FINAL STEP!
            switch (myType)
            {
                case "nets":
                    treeData = JSONModified;
                    return treeData; //SEND BACK THE JSON to the 
                    break;
                case "sites":
                    netsSites = JSONModified;
                    return netsSites; //SEND BACK THE JSON to the 
                    break;
                case "res":
                    sitesRes = JSONModified;
                    return sitesRes; //SEND BACK THE JSON to the 
                    break;
                case "comp":
                    resComp = JSONModified;
                    return resComp; //SEND BACK THE JSON to the 
                    break;
                default:
                    return '[{"data":"No tree data found..."}]';


            }
            //treeviewDetails.html to build the tree ONLY if called from tree
        }

    });
}


//**************************** STEP 1 ***************************
//Now process the JSON object and get the names of all the groups; albeit networks, sites, resources, components
function addPrefix(rawJSON) {

    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(rawJSON); // parse the JSON string to an actual array

    //Loop through all the groups of .... networks, sites, resources, components
    $.each(jsonArray, function(index, element) {

        element.data = element.name; //This can be INDEX or any other part...
        element.metadata = {
            id: element.id,
            note: element.notes
        };

        netsSites = _mySites(element.id);

        console.log("This is a site: " + netsSites);

        //If eval(getSites(element.id)) then make children
        if(netsSites !== "[]" || netsSites !== "")
        {
            element.children = eval(netsSites);
        }
    });
    console.log("Ret from GetInfo:  " + JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
    return JSON.stringify(jsonArray); // converts the array, with the new properties, back to a JSON string
}
//ERROR HANDLING
function errorHandler(e) {
    var msg = '';

    switch (e.code) {
        case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
            msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
            msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
            msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
            msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
            break;
        case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
            msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
            break;
        default:
            msg = 'Unknown Error';
            break;
    }

    console.Log('Error: ' + msg);
}


//In the basement, we're going to grab the sites, resources, and components
//With Callback...


    function _mySites(netID) {

        myNetwork = networksURL + "/" + netID + "/sites";

        console.log(myNetwork);

        return getInfo(myNetwork, function(data){});
    }
```

UPDATE... See all the code above... this should help.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your JSON that `mydata` is set to isn't valid? What is `getInfo`?

Comment: Where is `_mySites` defined? Is it in the same scope? I'm asking because you're assigning the function to a local variable.

Comment: What is `getInfo`?  Is that an AJAX call?  Because AJAX is *asynchronous*!  You can't return from an AJAX call, you probably need to use the callback (`function(data){}`).

Comment: Why does `getSites` have a `mydata` parameter?

Comment: Working the problem and trying your suggestions... stand by... thanks.

Comment: The JSON is completely valid...Daniel...  _mysites is not in the same scope... you're right.. fixing that and trying DanMan7...getInfo is a function that runs ajax and calls JSON to populate JSTree.  What I'm doing is populating the JSTree for all four levels at once... I'll post all the code if you'd like...

Comment: @Peter: If `getInfo` runs an AJAX call, then it can't return anything!  You need to do your `$.each(jsonArray` inside the callback.

Comment: Rocket, please see ALL the code above... the function buildTree(typJSON) is the starting function...

Comment: @Peter: I think you need to re-think this *entire* structure.  You're `getInfo` is calling `addPrefix` which is calling `_mySites` which is calling `getInfo` (which calls `addPrefix`...).  You're returning from callbacks and then ignoring the results.  You're returning `getInfo()` when it doesn't return anything.  This whole thing seems like a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a misspelling?

```
case "sties":
```

Comment: Thanks...D'oh!  Another Homer Simpson Moment

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
return getInfo(myNetwork, function(data){});
```

`getInfo` does not return anything.  It calls an AJAX request which is asynchronous.  So, `_mySites` returns undefined because that's what `getInfo` returns.

You need to use `getInfo`'s callback here.

```
function _mySites(netID, callback) {
    myNetwork = networksURL + "/" + netID + "/sites";
    console.log(myNetwork);
    getInfo(myNetwork, callback);
}
```

Then do:

```
_mySites(element.id, function(netsSites){
    console.log("This is a site: " + netsSites);
});
```

This means your `addPrefix` can't return anything because it's asynchronous.  You might need to re-think your entire structure here.